# Reconciling 2 general solutions to second order ODE

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A spring-mass system's behavior is described by the following ODE:

$$m{\ddot x}+kx=mg$$

Where dots indicate differentiation with respect to time, $t$. I have found two different general solutions from two different sources:

$$ x(t) = A {\cos ({\sqrt {\frac k m}}t}) +B{\sin ({\sqrt {\frac k m}}t}) +{\frac {mg} k} $$

and,

$$x(t) = C{\sin ({\sqrt{\frac k m}}}t+{\arctan({\sqrt{\frac k m}{\frac {x_0} {v_0}}}}))+{\frac {mg} k}$$

Where $A,B,C, k ,m,v_0,x_0,g$ are all constants and $t$ is the independent variable. I cannot figure out how to reconcile the two general solution and rewrite one as the other. There is no trigonmetric identity to relate the two and I am sure they must be the same expression as they plot very similarly. Can anyone provide some indications as to how I can rewrite the first form as the second form of the solution or vice versa?

Comment: Hint: use $$\sin{(\alpha +\beta)}=\sin{\alpha}\cos{\beta}+\cos{\alpha}\sin{\beta}$$
$$1+\tan^2{\gamma}=\frac{1}{\cos^2{\gamma}}$$
substitute $\gamma=\textrm{atan}{\alpha}$ for $\sin{(\textrm{atan}\alpha)}$ and do simmilar things with the $\cos{(\textrm{atan}\alpha)}$

Comment: Another hint: simplify your notation. Recommendations:
$$\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$$
$$\phi_0=\omega x_0/v_0$$
One always will treat nicely the simplified expressions.

Comment: You cannot reconcile your two solutions $$ x(t) = A {\cos ({\sqrt {\frac k m}}t}) +B{\sin ({\sqrt {\frac k m}}t}) +{\frac {mg} k} $$
$$x(t) = C{\sin ({\sqrt{\frac k m}}}t+{\arctan({\sqrt{\frac k m}{\frac {x_0} {v_0}}}}))+{\frac {mg} k}$$ because the first is general (they are made of two independent fonctions of $t$) while the second isn't the general solution (one function of $t$ only). Moreover, the second is false : if you put it into the ODE, you observe that it doesn't agree. Probably a typo or a mistake. Why don't you show what you have done ?

Comment: I've updated the original question to show the work I've done. Thanks.

Comment: To HBR: $$x(t) = C \sin  (\omega t +\arctan \phi)$$ $$x(t) = C\{ \sin \omega t \cos (\arctan \phi)+\cos (\omega t) \sin (\arctan \phi)\}$$ $$\gamma = \arctan \phi $$ $$x(t) = C\{\sin (\omega t)\cos \gamma+\cos(\omega t) \sin \gamma\}$$I'm not sure what the next step would be, it still looks very different and I have no idea where the $1+\tan^2{\gamma}=\frac{1}{\cos^2{\gamma}}$ comes in

Comment: @JJacquelin Consider the equation of harmonic oscillator $\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x = 0$. Its general solution is $x(t) = C_1 \cos(\omega t) + C_2 \sin (\omega t) $ which also can be rewritten as $x(t) = \mathcal{A} \sin (\omega t + \varphi)$ :) The second independent function just hides in this form which is exactly what OP has.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I made a mess with the parenthesis in reading the equation from user32882 : The term $arctan$ is inside the $\sin$, not outside as I wrongly have read it. My bad !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the full solution. Bear with me as it is quite long-winded:

We will need the following trigonmetric identity:
$$\begin{align}
\sin (\alpha + \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha
\tag 1\\
\end{align}
$$

We will only look at the homogeneous solution and ignore $ \frac {mg}k$, the particular part:

$$\begin{align}
x_h(t) = A\cos (\sqrt \frac k m t)+B\sin(\sqrt \frac k m t) 
\tag 2\\
\end{align}
$$

Factor out $\sqrt {A^2+B^2}$ from right hand side:
$$ \begin{align}
x_h(t)=
\sqrt {A^2+B^2} \left(   \frac A {\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}\cos (\sqrt \frac k m t)  +   \frac B {\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}\sin (\sqrt \frac k m t)   \right)
\tag 3\\
\end{align}
$$

Now, note that:

$$\begin{align}
\left( \frac A {\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}\right)^2+\left( \frac B {\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}\right)^2 = 1
\tag 4\\
\end{align}
$$

And also that:

$$\begin{align}
x_h(t)=
\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi=1
\tag 5\\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, there exists an angle $\phi $ such that $\frac A {\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}=\sin \phi$ and such that $\frac B {\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}=\cos \phi$. Substituting these back into Eqn (3) we obtain:

$$ \begin{align}
x_h(t)=
\sqrt {A^2+B^2} \left(   \sin \phi \cos (\sqrt \frac k m t)  +   \cos \phi \sin (\sqrt \frac k m t)   \right)
\tag 6\\
\end{align}
$$

We can now use the trigonometric identity (Eqn (1)) to simplify Eqn (6) to the following:

$$ \begin{align}
x_h(t)=
\sqrt {A^2+B^2}\sin(\phi + \sqrt \frac k m t)
\tag 7\\
\end{align}
$$

Now, $\tan \phi = \frac {\sin \phi} {\cos \phi} = \frac A B $ (Refer to Eqns 4 and 5). Therefore $\phi=\arctan \frac A B$. and substituting this into Eqn. (7) we end up with:

$$ \begin{align}
x_h(t)=
\sqrt {A^2+B^2}\sin(\arctan \frac A B + \sqrt \frac k m t)
\tag 8\\
\end{align}
$$

What remains is to solve for constants $A$ and $B$. This is most easily done by using initial conditions below:

$$x(0) = x_0$$ and, $$ \dot x(0) = v_0$$ Where the dot symbolizes differentiation with respect to t. We take our full solution $x(t) = x_h(t)+x_p(t)$ where $x_p(t) = \frac {mg} k$ and apply the initial conditions.

$$\begin{align}
x(t) = A\cos (\sqrt \frac k m t)+B\sin(\sqrt \frac k m t) +\frac {mg} k
\tag 9\\
\end{align}
$$

$$\begin{align}
\dot x(t) = B \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \cos \left(t \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\right)-A \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \sin \left(t \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\right)
\tag {10}\\
\end{align}$$

Substituting initial conditions:

$$\begin{align}
 x(0)=x_0 = A+\frac{g m}{k}
\tag {11}\\
\end{align}
$$

And 
$$\begin{align}
\dot x(0) = v_0 = B \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}
\tag {12}\\
\end{align}
$$

Which yields $A = x_0-\frac {mg} k $ and $B = v_0 \sqrt \frac m k$