# Same algebraic function behaves differently when it's form changes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054150/reconciling-2-general-solutions-to-second-order-ode/2055753#2055753) I succeeded in converting the solution of the ODE $m{\ddot x}+kx=mg$ from this form:

\begin{align}
x(t) = A\cos \left(\sqrt \frac k m t\right)+B\sin\left(\sqrt \frac k m t\right) +\frac {mg} k
\tag 1\\
\end{align}

to this form:
\begin{align}
x(t)=
\sqrt {A^2+B^2}\sin\left(\arctan \frac A B + \sqrt \frac k m t\right)+\frac {mg} k
\tag 2\\
\end{align}

Applying the initial conditions $x(0) = x_0$ and $\dot x(0) = v_0 $ to the first form (Eqn. 1), I ended up with $A = x_0-\frac {mg} k$ and $B = v_0 \sqrt \frac m k$. Substituting this into Eqn. 1, we get:

\begin{align}
x(t) = \left(x_0-\frac {mg} k\right)\cos \left(\sqrt \frac k m t\right)+\left(v_0 \sqrt \frac m k\right)\sin\left(\sqrt \frac k m t\right) +\frac {mg} k
\tag 3\\
\end{align}

Substituting this into Eqn. 2, we get:

\begin{align}
x(t)=
\sqrt {\left(x_0-\frac {mg} k\right)^2+\left(v_0 \sqrt \frac m k\right)^2}\sin\left(\arctan \frac { x_0-\frac {mg} k} {v_0 \sqrt \frac m k} + \sqrt \frac k m t\right)+\frac {mg} k
\tag 4\\
\end{align}

My initial conditions happen to be $x(0) =x_0 = 0$ and $\dot x(0) = v_0=0$. It can be observed that Eqn  3. can handle $v_0 = 0$ whereas Eqn. 4 cannot. Why, if they are essentially the same functionn, do they behave differently for $v_0= 0$ ?

Comment: That is because when $v_0=0$, in equation (3), the $\sin$ component becomes $0$. There is only the $\cos$ component left. In Equation (4), when $v_0\rightarrow 0$, the $\arctan(..)$ goes to $\pi/2$. Then $\sin(\pi/2+..)$ is exactly $\cos(..)$.

Comment: Interesting. Therefore it is impossible to substitute 0 into equation 4 and thus one cannot plot it at $v_0 = 0$ but only as $v_0$ $\textit{approaches} $ $0$. Does this not make them two different functions then? is Eqn (4) even a function? Does there exist a deeper reason for why the transformation makes it behave like this?

Comment: You'll have to make $v_0=0$ a special case. Give equation (4) with the condition $v_0\ne 0$. When $v_0=0$, $x(t)$ is just represented by $\cos$. This is in some sense like projection to $\sin$ component or $\cos$ component. If $x(t)$ does not have $\sin$ component, you have to represent it using $\cos$ component only.

Comment: Ok. If you like you can post your these comments as a final answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Equation 4 can handle $v_0=0$ if you use a "better" arc tangent function that returns the angle of the vector with components (denominator, numerator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when $v_0=0$, in equation (3), the $\sin$ component becomes $0$. There is only the $\cos$ component left. In Equation (4), when $v_0\rightarrow 0$, the $\arctan(..)$ goes to $\pi/2$. Then $\sin(\pi/2+..)$ is exactly $\cos(..)$.

You'll have to make $v_0=0$ a special case. Give equation (4) with the condition $v_0\ne 0$. When $v_0=0$, $x(t)$ is just represented by $\cos$. This is in some sense like projection to $\sin$ component or $\cos$ component. If $x(t)$ does not have $\sin$ component, you have to represent it using $\cos$ component only.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing an identity like

$$A\cos t+B\sin t=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos\left(t-\arctan\frac BA\right).$$

When $A=0$, anyway, it reduces to

$$B\sin t=|B|\cos\left(t\pm\arctan\frac\pi2\right),$$ (depending on the sign of $B$) and this cannot be expressed with the arc tangent function.

The complex numbers allow a more general representation with the "argument" operator,

$$A\cos t+B\sin t=|A+iB|\cos\left(t-\angle(A+iB)\right).$$

Alternatively,

$$A\cos t+B\sin t=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos\left(t-\arctan_2(B,A)\right),$$
where the function $\arctan_2$ cares about the quadrants.

---

Similar reasoning holds for the $\sin(t+\phi)$ representation.

Comment: Thanks Yves. This is a more thorough explanation and provides added perspective/depth to KittyL's answer.